# Getting the list of objects in another file to update for appending

Tags: append, data-blocks

I need to append a large number of objects from an external file. To facilitate that, I created a version of the file that is stripped down just to the objects I need, so I could just select all and append.

But, I can't get the file that is being appended into to see the updated list of objects in the file being appended from. It still sees a whole bunch of objects that no longer exist in that file. I tried restarting Blender, and even restarting the computer, but it is pulling a reference list of what is in that file from somewhere that still remembers all those other objects.

I tried appending everything anyhow, thinking maybe it would discard things it can't find, but wonder of wonders, it imports things that no longer exist in that file. I have checked and rechecked - yes, I deleted them, yes, there they are, appended from beyond the grave. I purged orphan data and it didn't help.

It's hard to usefully show this problem, but here is a screenshot of the object list according to what is there for appending, in the foreground on the left, and at the right side in the window behind, the object list in the file with the objects to be appended. Both are partial lists. All the ones on the left with numbers at the end, or that end in _Col, and others too - they don't exist.

[image]

How can I get rid of this ghost data?

Edit: Once I realized I could append a complete Collection, this stopped being a problem. But batFINGER raised a point that seems like a likely explanation, except it isn't.

There is only one collection in the file, I had set it up that way but had it in my head I couldn't append it. However the data is stored, it isn't in a collection.

I have temporarily uploaded the file to Blend-Exchange, because this issue is weird, so maybe he'd like to look at it. I've checked it as much as I can, and have no explanation for the presence of the extra data, other than to say this is an old file that has gone through many iterations during which I was largely a novice user of Blender who did odd things.

[image]

Comment: Could you open the file where you have deleted the objects and check in the outliner if they are still listed under orphan data? If they are, click the purge button.

Comment: @rjg - Yeah, I did that. It still happens.

Comment: Right, you already wrote that. Sorry, missed it.

Comment: Are there any .blend1 files around?

Comment: No, deleting .blend1 files doesn't change anything.

Comment: I see now it is possible to append a collection, and in that case, there is no problem with deleted objects continuing to show up. That made this far easier.

Comment: That may be both the solution and the issue. If they're there (the objects) they exist in file, but aren't linked to a scene. Could be that a collection gives an object a user. (assuming you haven't set use fake user)  If so remove the unwanted collection, then the unwanted objects will be orphans (in theory at least)

Comment: @batFINGER the interesting thing is, because i didn't realize i could append a whole collection, i made a file that only had the collection i wanted, so i could append every object in it. (I think i'd found i couldn't link a collection and got confused.) There is no other collection in this file that's saving that data. It's supposed to be gone. That bit is curious enough maybe i'll even add a screenshot showing that.